# Why does the Faddeeva function not look similar to the convolution of a Lorentzian and a Gaussian?

Tags: python, scipy

Since the faddeeva is a convolution of a gaussian and a lorenztian i would expect them to look vaguely similar, however when I add a non-resonant contribution, the scipy.wofz does not gain the expected shape.

Don't worry about the amplitudes, I am just wondering about the overall line-shape

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import wofz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(2185,2300,1000)
gamma = 2
sigma = 2
z = ((2230 - x) + 1j*gamma)/sigma
plt.plot(x,np.abs(1/(2230-x-1j*gamma)+5)**2,color='green',label='lorenztian')
plt.plot(x, (np.exp(-((2230-x)**2)/(2*sigma**2))+5)**2,color='red',label='gaussian')
plt.plot(x,np.abs(wofz(z)+5)**2,color='blue',label = 'faddeeva')
convolve = np.convolve(1/(2230-x-1j*gamma),np.exp(-((2230-x)**2)/(2*sigma**2)),mode='same')*(x[1]-x[0])
plt.plot(x,np.abs(convolve+5)**2,label = 'convolution')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

There is also a strange lump (non-technical term) at the end range of the convolution for whatever reason.

I tried adding the convolution which should in theory give a similar line-shape but it clearly does not.